# Sharepoint - Export all data to csv with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint

I am attempting to use a script provided by Thriggle [See His Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656458/export-all-the-columns-with-their-data-values-in-a-list) and am having some issues with it.  It works almost flawlessly for what I am doing - EXCEPT - it doesn't export the Created By, Created Date, Modified By, and Modified Date.

Is there a way to add those fields into the script?

Here is his script:

```
$url = "$url"
$listName = "$list"
$path ="c:\ColumnsOfList.csv"

$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)
$fields = $list.ContentTypes | %{ $_.FieldLinks } | select Name, DisplayName
$items = @() #array to store objects representing list items
$list.items | %{ 
    $item = $_; 
    $hash = @{}; #hash table to store field name-value pairs
    $fields | %{ $hash[$_.DisplayName] = $item[$_.Name]  }; 
    $items += new-object psobject -Property $hash }
$items | Export-Csv -Path $path
```

Comment: Can you list `$list.items[0] | fl *` to see if these properties are already there? I don't have SharePoint environment to test unfortunately so I cannot do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this one](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html).

Here is my test code.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://sp:12001"

#Get the Target List
$list = $web.Lists["OrderDetails"]

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()

 #Get All List items where Status is "In Progress"
 $list.Items | foreach {
 $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["Title"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OrderDate" -value $_["OrderDate"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "CreatedBy" -value $_["Author"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Created" -value $_["Created"]

 #Add the object with property to an Array
 $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
 }
 #Export the result Array to CSV file
 $ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "C:\Lee\ListData.csv" -NoTypeInformation                       

#Dispose the web Object
$web.Dispose()
```